# strpos: finding a value in .ini file

Tags: php, newline, ini, strpos

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
if (strpos($stringt, $key . '=') === false) {
    ...some code...
}
```

and is supposed to check if a particular key=value pair exists in an .ini file.  The .ini file is just a PHP .ini file full of KEY=String values, one per line.

The problem is that if a shorter key happens to be present within a longer key, the line will return true instead of false.  For example, if a key/value PROBLEM=problem exists and you check using: $key = 'EN', the routine will return true because $strpos will match 'EN=' within the longer string 'HAPPEN='.  How can I get strpos to match a key only from the start of a new line (I tried '\n' . $key . '=' and that didn't work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (strpos($stringt, "\n" . $key . '=') === false) {
    ...some code...
}
```

You had to use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

I would just use PHP's built-in INI parser:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

```
print_r(parse_ini_file('yourinihere.ini'));
```

Comment: This would probably have worked except my .ini files are actually not native PHP .ini files and they don't strictly conform to formatting conventions for PHP.